# Error Reporting from 0 to 1 makes my web app crash

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling, e-notices

Earlier today we found out a lot of table locks in the database on our production environment, which resulted in 500 errors anywhere randomly in the system. Upon closely debugging, it was found that, there was error_reporting flag set to 0 on of the files, which increased PHP WARNINGS and NOTICES, to so much extent that the app used to crash.

Once we removed this, all 500 errors started to appear in the system, for various business work flows and functions. Is there any magical way to fix it, rather than going to each of this warning and notices, and solve it in the whole code base?

Comment: Not following your logic! `error_reporting(0);` turns Off error reporting, that wont crash your app! However lots of errors is well known for crashing an app. So why would you not fix them? Did you change the version of PHP you are using by any chance

Comment: No, there is no simple solution to this problem. However, the best solution would be to fix the errors one by one, before the number of issues increases further

Comment: I also do no follow how some database table locks is related to PHP Errors, if the PHP code is causing the table lock, then you have no choice but to fix them surely. If the code is not causing the table locks, then Why are you mentioning the database issues. If the table locks caused the PHP errors, then you need to know what caused the database issues and fix that wheever it is